# How to add value inside an array of array in mongoose by value find by ID?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to add the data inside the order products_id array

I tried to push the array by find it by user id and then add push it inside the products_id but i won't able to add the data.

```
User.findById(user_id,(err,user)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        const lastOrderId = user.order.slice(-1)[0]._id
        //console.log(cb.order.slice(-1)[0]._id);

    User.update({'order[0]._id': lastOrderId}, {$push: {'order.0.$.products_id': 123}},{safe:true,upsert:true})


    /*User.findOneAndUpdate({'_id' : user_id, 'order._id': lastOrderId} 
    ,{$push: [{'order[0].products_id': [123123]}]},{safe:true,upsert:true})*/
})
```

My User Schema

```
 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        user_name: {type:String,require: true},
        email:  {type:String, require: true},
        password: {type:String,require:true},
        full_name: {type:String},
        order: [{
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            products_id: [],
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }]
    })
```

After updating i want

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        _id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        user_name: {type:String,require: true},
        email:  {type:String, require: true},
        password: {type:String,require:true},
        full_name: {type:String},
        order: [{
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            products_id: [5d5d7a7ea0c4aaf6212993ec, 5d627a962a5c637e7a0d5d1c, 5d627a49fa24ba7d15451afb],
            date: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            }
        }]
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrayFilter for this.You can do it like this.

```
 User.update({user_id},{$set: { 'order.$[ord]': lastOrderId },
 $push: {'order.$[ord].products.$[prd]':123}
 }, {
 arrayFilters: [{'_id': user_id}]
 })
```

Comment: User.update({userID},{$set: {'order.$[ord]': lastProductID},$push : {'order.$[ord].products_id.$[prd]':123}}, {
        arrayFilters: [{'_id': userID}]
        })

Comment: Yes, it is correct but you share which error you get so i will check it again.

Comment: I am actually writing on node js so i get 500 error when i use no other things are showing

Comment: const userID = req.user._id
    info = [];
    info["user_id"] = userID
    const lastProductID = req.user.order[0]._id
    console.log(productID)
    User.update({userID},{$set: {'order.$[ord]': lastProductID},$push : {'order.$[ord].products_id.$[prd]':123}}).exec()
    .then(productsUpdate => {
            console.log(productsUpdate)
        })
    .catch(err=>{console.log(err)})

Comment: Ok,i will check.